# Jquery - create function from code.?

Tags: jquery, function

I have this code that I'd like to turn into a function.

`str` is a string.

`names` is an array

`id` is a string

```
var str = ',' + id + ',' + name;

names = names.map(function(value) {
if( value.indexOf(id) > -1 ) { //if id is in value
    return (value.indexOf('add') === 0 ? 'add' : 'edit') + str; //if value starts with 'add' then return 'add'+str, otherwise return 'edit'+str
}
return value; //if id not in value, return value
});

if ( ($.inArray('edit' + str, names) == -1  && $.inArray('add' + str, names) == -1)   ) { //If 'edit'+str is not in the names array AND 'add'+str is not in the names array
    names.push('edit' + str) //add 'edit'+str to the names array
}
```

I've tried this but it didn't seem to work:

```
function func_name (array_name, id, str) {
    array_name = array_name.map(function(value) {
    if( value.indexOf(id) > -1 ) { //if id is in value
        return (value.indexOf('add') === 0 ? 'add' : 'edit') + str; //if value starts with 'add' then return 'add'+str, otherwise return 'edit'+str
    }
    return value; //if id not in value, return value
    });

    if ( ($.inArray('edit' + str, array_name) == -1  && $.inArray('add' + str, array_name) == -1)   ) { //If 'edit'+str is not in the array_name array AND 'add'+str is not in the array_name array
        array_name.push('edit' + str) //add 'edit'+str to the array_name array
    }
}
```

The calling it using:

`func_name (users, user_id, str)`

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: *"didn't seem to work"* is not a useful problem description. What is it meant to do, and what did it do instead when you tried it? What errors did you get? Please also put a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem in a Stack Snippet (the `<>` toolbar button). Make sure the snippet replicates the problem when you run it.

Comment: Hi Sorry you are correct, that wasn't a very helpful description. It should lookup an ID in an array and if it starts with add then return `add+str`, if not return `edit+str`, failing that just return the other values. Finally if it doesn't exist add it to the array. I ran it trying to output the results from the array and nothing appeared.  When run not as s function, then it worked.